# Filter data using multiple object value in javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

**Firstly sorry for this long post.** I know this question has been asked before, but existing solutions do not seem to work for my case. But that doesn't solve my purpose.

My sample data looks like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 26201,
    title: "BusinessNZ Services Index",
    country: "USD",
    date: "19th Jun 6:30 PM",
    impact: "Low",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "51.4",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Sunday",
  },
  {
    id: 26202,
    title: "Rightmove HPI m/m",
    country: "GBP",
    date: "19th Jun 7:01 PM",
    impact: "Low",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "2.1%",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Sunday",
  },
  {
    id: 26203,
    title: "German PPI m/m",
    country: "EUR",
    date: "20th Jun 2:00 AM",
    impact: "Low",
    forecast: "1.5%",
    previous: "2.8%",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Sunday",
  },
  {
    id: 26204,
    title: "MPC Member Haskel Speaks",
    country: "GBP",
    date: "20th Jun 4:00 AM",
    impact: "Low",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Monday",
  },
  {
    id: 26205,
    title: "Bank Holiday",
    country: "USD",
    date: "20th Jun 9:00 AM",
    impact: "Holiday",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Monday",
  },
  {
    id: 26206,
    title: "MPC Member Mann Speaks",
    country: "GBP",
    date: "20th Jun 9:00 AM",
    impact: "Low",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Monday",
  },
  {
    id: 26207,
    title: "ECB President Lagarde Speaks",
    country: "EUR",
    date: "20th Jun 9:00 AM",
    impact: "Medium",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Monday",
  },
  {
    id: 26208,
    title: "ECB President Lagarde Speaks",
    country: "EUR",
    date: "20th Jun 11:00 AM",
    impact: "Medium",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Monday",
  },
];
```

I want to filter data using multiple objects whose value is true.

sample object:

```
const countrys = {
  NZD: false,
  AUD: true,
  CAD: false,
  EUR: false,
  GBP: false,
  USD: true,
  CHF: false,
  JPY: false,
  CNY: false,
};
    
const days = {
  Sunday: true,
  Monday: false,
  Tuesday: true,
  Wednesday: false,
  Thursday: false,
  Friday: false,
};

const impacts = {
  Low: true,
  Medium: true,
  High: false,
  Holiday: false,
};
```

My filter data will be all object true values if any or nothing.

For this example, the result will be my data's first element.

```
   {
            id: 26201,
            title: "BusinessNZ Services Index",
            country: "USD",
            date: "19th Jun 6:30 PM",
            impact: "Low",
            forecast: "",
            previous: "51.4",
            created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
            updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
            day: "Sunday",
}
```

**If there are one or more true values then check using this object or i want to just skip that object**.

**I want to make a filter like this one**  [link](https://e8x.e8funding.com/economic-calendar)

Comment: what you tried so far? post your code in question.

Comment: I try to filter data using country, days and impact

Comment: minimum one is true or all must be true in country, days and impacts object

Comment: If one true than just return one. if multiple is two we have to return multiple.  basically we need to check every object if there is any true than filter data using this or no true than just skip.

Comment: @soykot2910 did you check my answer ?

Comment: @Batuhan wait a minute dude.

Comment: @Batuhan Yeah i checked your ans. if i give  all impacts object false it return [] array. but i want to filter for other two object like country and days

Comment: Yeah it is the filter logic if you provide multiple conditions it searchs all true conditions. That means you need to if one filter false or falsy it must be return other matched filter conditions ? Am i right ?

Comment: @Batuhan i want some things like this [link](https://e8x.e8funding.com/economic-calendar)

Comment: Links to external sites can be interesting (I don't have access to it though), but all *necessary* logic should be explained within the question, not behind a link.

Comment: @trincot I am sorry for that. But i want to do like that link that why i share that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this generic by assuming that the names of the filter objects correspond to the property names in the data, but in "plural" forms, like `countrys` for filtering on `country`.

You could provide all those filter objects in one object where these names are properties. In the example, this filter object would be `{countrys, days, impacts}`

Code:

```js
const multiFilter = (data, filters) => data.filter(o =>
    Object.entries(filters).every(([key, bools]) =>
        !Object.values(bools).includes(true) || bools[o[key.slice(0, -1)]]
    )
);

const data = [{id: 26201,title: "BusinessNZ Services Index",country: "USD",date: "19th Jun 6:30 PM",impact: "Low",forecast: "",previous: "51.4",created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",day: "Sunday",},{id: 26202,title: "Rightmove HPI m/m",country: "GBP",date: "19th Jun 7:01 PM",impact: "Low",forecast: "",previous: "2.1%",created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",day: "Sunday",},{id: 26203,title: "German PPI m/m",country: "EUR",date: "20th Jun 2:00 AM",impact: "Low",forecast: "1.5%",previous: "2.8%",created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",day: "Sunday",},{id: 26204,title: "MPC Member Haskel Speaks",country: "GBP",date: "20th Jun 4:00 AM",impact: "Low",forecast: "",previous: "",created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",day: "Monday",},{id: 26205,title: "Bank Holiday",country: "USD",date: "20th Jun 9:00 AM",impact: "Holiday",forecast: "",previous: "",created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",day: "Monday",},{id: 26206,title: "MPC Member Mann Speaks",country: "GBP",date: "20th Jun 9:00 AM",impact: "Low",forecast: "",previous: "",created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",day: "Monday",},{id: 26207,title: "ECB President Lagarde Speaks",country: "EUR",date: "20th Jun 9:00 AM",impact: "Medium",forecast: "",previous: "",created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",day: "Monday",},{id: 26208,title: "ECB President Lagarde Speaks",country: "EUR",date: "20th Jun 11:00 AM",impact: "Medium",forecast: "",previous: "",created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",day: "Monday",},];
const countrys = {NZD: false,AUD: true,CAD: false,EUR: false,GBP: false,USD: true,CHF: false,JPY: false,CNY: false,};
const days = {Sunday: true,Monday: false,Tuesday: true,Wednesday: false,Thursday: false,Friday: false,};
const impacts = {Low: true,Medium: true,High: false,Holiday: false,};

console.log(multiFilter(data, {countrys, days, impacts}));
```

Comment: Firstly thank you. But i want to more specefit. let's think about a scenario where in days object only sunday is true  and another two object impacts and country everything is false. for this case ans will be every data where day is sunday.

Comment: So are you saying that when everything is false in one object, it should act as if everything is true? Or are you saying that it is *enough* that a data object only has one property that leads to a true in **one** of the filter objects?

Comment: I want somethings like this  [link](https://e8x.e8funding.com/economic-calendar)

Comment: I don't have access to that site. Can you just explain in your question, which of the logics I mention above you need? For instance, do you get the expected result when `every` is changed to `some` in my answer code? (I suppose not, because in the example you said you just wanted one result, which made me conclude that all properties of a data object must lead to a true value in a filter object).

Comment: https://prnt.sc/EcWweOUsZ-MS  https://prnt.sc/9HAbBQN9uJ29 this might help you to understand

Comment: Sorry, screenshots are not going to help. Please explain with boolean logic. Again, can you confirm that when a filter object has all its values to false, that it should act as if that filter object was not there at all?

Comment: Yeah, just skip that object. if there are no true values and filter for other object

Comment: OK, but if there is at least a true value, then **all** those filter objects should give a true value at the *same* time for the same object, right? I updated my answer with an extra condition to deal with an "all-false-filter-object"

Comment: ` const countrys = {
NZD: false,
AUD: true,
CAD: false,
EUR: false,
GBP: false,
USD: true,
CHF: false,
JPY: false,
CNY: false,
};

const days = {
Sunday: true,
Monday: false,
Tuesday: true,
Wednesday: false,
Thursday: false,
Friday: false,
};

const impacts = {
Low: false,
Medium: false,
High: false,
Holiday: false,
}; ` for this case filter will work for country and days object. impacts part will be skipped

Comment: OK, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Finally, I was able to explain you.

Comment: Yes, but you could just have answered "Yes" to my first question in this thread ;-)

Comment: Sorry dude. I thought the live website link might help you to understand clearly. By the way, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

here is some piece of code

```js
const data = [
 {
    id: 26201,
    title: "BusinessNZ Services Index",
    country: "USD",
    date: "19th Jun 6:30 PM",
    impact: "Low",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "51.4",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Sunday",
  },
  {
    id: 26202,
    title: "Rightmove HPI m/m",
    country: "GBP",
    date: "19th Jun 7:01 PM",
    impact: "Low",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "2.1%",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Sunday",
  },
  {
    id: 26203,
    title: "German PPI m/m",
    country: "EUR",
    date: "20th Jun 2:00 AM",
    impact: "Low",
    forecast: "1.5%",
    previous: "2.8%",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Sunday",
  },
  {
    id: 26204,
    title: "MPC Member Haskel Speaks",
    country: "GBP",
    date: "20th Jun 4:00 AM",
    impact: "Low",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Monday",
  },
  {
    id: 26205,
    title: "Bank Holiday",
    country: "USD",
    date: "20th Jun 9:00 AM",
    impact: "Holiday",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Monday",
  },
  {
    id: 26206,
    title: "MPC Member Mann Speaks",
    country: "GBP",
    date: "20th Jun 9:00 AM",
    impact: "Low",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Monday",
  },
  {
    id: 26207,
    title: "ECB President Lagarde Speaks",
    country: "EUR",
    date: "20th Jun 9:00 AM",
    impact: "Medium",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Monday",
  },
  {
    id: 26208,
    title: "ECB President Lagarde Speaks",
    country: "EUR",
    date: "20th Jun 11:00 AM",
    impact: "Medium",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Monday",
  },
];

const countrys = {
  NZD: false,
  AUD: true,
  CAD: false,
  EUR: false,
  GBP: false,
  USD: true,
  CHF: false,
  JPY: false,
  CNY: false,
};
    
const days = {
  Sunday: true,
  Monday: false,
  Tuesday: true,
  Wednesday: false,
  Thursday: false,
  Friday: false,
};

const impacts = {
  Low: true,
  Medium: true,
  High: false,
  Holiday: false,
};

const newData = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const check = countrys[val.country] && days[val.day] && impacts[val.impact]
    if (check) {
        acc.push(val)
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log('newData', newData)
```

Comment: just change `&&` to `||` condition so you get object with minimum one true;

Comment: Firstly thank you. But i want to more specefit. let's think about a scenario where in days object only sunday is true  and another two object impacts and country everything is false. for this case ans will be every data where day is sunday.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write the whole thing out but I think you want to do something like this:

```
const filterFunction = entry => {
  const dayCheck = days[entry.day]
  if (!dayCheck) return false
  // do this for all criteria
  return true
}

const filteredEntries = entries.filter(filterFunction)
```

I don't particularly like this method of doing things because it relies on global variables in the filters. I would refactor this into a filter class.

```
class EntryFilterer {
  constructor(dayFilters, countryFilters){
    this.dayFilters = dayFilters || {}
    this.countryFilters = countryFilters || {}
  }

  filter(entry){
    if (!this.dayFilters[entry.day]) return false
    if (!this.countryFilters[entry.country]) return false
    return true

  }
}
```

Then you have some more flexible code which can be used with different filters.

```
const filterer = EntryFilterer(days, countries)
const filteredEntries = entries.filter(filterer.filter)
```

Comment: Firstly thank you. But i want to more specefit. let's think about a scenario where in days object only sunday is true  and another two object impacts and country everything is false. for this case ans will be every data where day is sunday.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fully-functional dynamic search approach. It uses given data's keys as filter keys. That means you can extend your filter logic via adding some extra keys into your `filterDefinitions` object.

```js
const data = [{
    id: 26201,
    title: "BusinessNZ Services Index",
    country: "USD",
    date: "19th Jun 6:30 PM",
    impact: "Low",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "51.4",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Sunday",
  },
  {
    id: 26202,
    title: "Rightmove HPI m/m",
    country: "GBP",
    date: "19th Jun 7:01 PM",
    impact: "Low",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "2.1%",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Sunday",
  },
  {
    id: 26203,
    title: "German PPI m/m",
    country: "EUR",
    date: "20th Jun 2:00 AM",
    impact: "Low",
    forecast: "1.5%",
    previous: "2.8%",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Sunday",
  },
  {
    id: 26204,
    title: "MPC Member Haskel Speaks",
    country: "GBP",
    date: "20th Jun 4:00 AM",
    impact: "Low",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Monday",
  },
  {
    id: 26205,
    title: "Bank Holiday",
    country: "USD",
    date: "20th Jun 9:00 AM",
    impact: "Holiday",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Monday",
  },
  {
    id: 26206,
    title: "MPC Member Mann Speaks",
    country: "GBP",
    date: "20th Jun 9:00 AM",
    impact: "Low",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Monday",
  },
  {
    id: 26207,
    title: "ECB President Lagarde Speaks",
    country: "EUR",
    date: "20th Jun 9:00 AM",
    impact: "Medium",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Monday",
  },
  {
    id: 26208,
    title: "ECB President Lagarde Speaks",
    country: "EUR",
    date: "20th Jun 11:00 AM",
    impact: "Medium",
    forecast: "",
    previous: "",
    created_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    updated_at: "2022-06-23T13:15:02.000000Z",
    day: "Monday",
  },
];

const countrys = {
  NZD: false,
  AUD: true,
  CAD: false,
  EUR: false,
  GBP: false,
  USD: true,
  CHF: false,
  JPY: false,
  CNY: false,
};

const days = {
  Sunday: true,
  Monday: false,
  Tuesday: true,
  Wednesday: false,
  Thursday: false,
  Friday: false,
};

const impacts = {
  Low: true,
  Medium: true,
  High: false,
  Holiday: false,
};


function filterEngine(array, filters) {
  var filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
  return array.filter(function(item) {
    // validates all filter criteria
    return filterKeys.every(function(key) {
      // ignores non-function predicates
      if (typeof filters[key] !== 'function') {
        return true;
      }

      return filters[key](item[key]);
    });
  });
}

const filterDefinitions = {
  country: function(country) {
    return !!countrys[country];
  },
  day: function(day) {
    return !!days[day];
  },
  impact: function(impact) {
    return !!impacts[impact];
  }
  // you can extend your filter by adding keys that existing on data.
};

console.log(filterEngine(data, filterDefinitions));
```

You must define the filter logic in object:

```js
const filterDefinitions = {
  country: function(country) {
    return !!countrys[country];
  },
  day: function(day) {
    return !!days[day];
  },
  impact: function(impact) {
    return !!impacts[impact];
  }
  // you can extend your filter by adding keys that existing on data
  // key: function(value) {
  // // Filter logic for field comes here.
  // }
};
```

You can use like this:

```js
const result = filterEngine(data, filterDefinitions);
```